# Match parameters in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like the following;

```
var x = "test/foo/4/bar/3"
```

and I have a pattern

```
var y = "test/foo/{id}/bar/{age}"
```

Is it possible via regex to use the pattern to extract the numbers 4 and 3 from variable "x"?

Comment: Will the string *always* take that form? five components, separated by slashes?

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest, if the string-format is predictably in that format, avoiding regular expressions:

```
var str = "test/foo/4/bar/3",
    parts = str.split('/'),
    id = parts[2],
    age = parts[4];
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ynJmA/).

If, however, you feel you really *must* use regular expressions (and complicate your life), there's the possibility of:

```
var str = "test/foo/4/bar/3",
    parts = str.split('/'),
    id = str.match(/\/(\d+)\//)[1],
    age = str.match(/\/(\d+)$/)[1];
console.log(id,age);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ynJmA/1/).

References:

- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions).
- [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Answer (score 0):

If you have non-constant pattern, and your pattern is "test/name1/value1/name2/value2", check this:

```
function match(url, variables) {
    /* regexp */
    function MatchRE(variable) {
        return new RegExp("/" + variable + "\\/([^\\/]+)");
    }

    var regExp, result = {};
    for (var i=0; i<variables.length; i++) {
        regExp = new MatchRE(variables[i]);
        if (regExp.test(url)) {
            result[variables[i]] = RegExp.$1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

example:
    match("test/foo/4/bar/3", ["foo", "bar"]); //Object {foo: "4"}
    match("test/foo/testValue1/bar/testValue2/buz/testValue3", ["foo", "buz"]); //Object {foo: "testValue1", buz: "testValue3"}
```